# Fortran compiler options not recognized

Tags: fortran

I am using a numerical model that is sensitive to the precision of numerics. With my old ifort compiler I successfully used the Fortran flags 
"fp-model precise"

I recently installed intel compiler composer_xe_2015.3.187. It does not recognize the Fortran flag 
"fp-model precise". 
This is the exact error that I get

*f95: error: precise: No such file or directory
f95: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fp-model’*

I am afraid if I would be sacrificing my efficiency in lieu of the new compiler or is the new one inherently able to maintain precision.

Comment: Agreed.  `f95` probably isn't ifort, try `f95 -v`.

Comment: Doing f95-v shows me a gcc version 4.8.2. However, i have the ifort compiler in my path and I can see it by doing "which ifort"

Comment: Then simply run `ifort` instead of `f95`.

Comment: Yes, I had tried resolving the issue with the comments in that post but that was not helping the issue. I should have followed better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler you are invoking with the name `f95` is not Intel Fortran.  Based on the error message, I'm guessing it is actually the GNU Fortran compiler, but you can check for sure by running `f95 -v` to see what the compiler identifies itself as.

Intel Fortran 15 still supports the option `-fp-model precise`.

Before invoking ifort, you need to setup its environment, e.g.

```
source /path/to/intel/bin/ifortvars.sh intel64
```

for the 64 bit compiler.  You can then invoke the compiler as `ifort`.

Comment: Thanks Casey, I am able to invoke ifort.  By checking f95 -v, I can also see that it is detecting GNU Fortran compiler. Therefore, t is not using ifort. However, in my makefile I have ifort specified. So I am not sure why it is reverting to use GNU fortran compiler. I am able to compile a separate simple program with ifort.

Comment: @TarandeepKalra makefiles often use the value of $FC to determine the fortran compiler.  You can try setting FC=ifort in the makefile or running `FC=ifort make` and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, it is weird but my FC is set equal to ifort.